# getting user to input 10 numbers and then sum them in python

Tags: python, input, sum

I'm studying python and doing some practice and come across with the following problem:

> 10 numbers are given in the input. Read them and print their sum. Use as few variables as you can.

I'm try to get 10 numbers with input function and then sum all of them but cant do it.

here are the codes I've been trying:

```
for i in range(0,10):
    a=int(input())
    n=0

for i in range(a):
    n+=1
    print(n)
```

with the above code, the variable `a` gets only the last integer so it does not sum them.

I tried to list 'a' but it didnot work either. I tried to use `sum()` function as below but it didnot work either.

```
for i in range(0,10):
    a=sum(int(input()))
```

can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

```
n=0

for i in range(0,10):
    a=int(input())
    n += a

print(n)
```

First, you initialize the counter - `n` and in every step you add the input to the counter.

Answer (score 2):

The loop needs to be in the argument to `sum()`

```
total = sum([int(input()) for _ in range(10)])
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are Two methods to finish it:

---

1. Use a variable to cumulative each input

```py
s = 0
for _ in range(0, 10):
  s += int(input())
return s
```

---

2. Record the input into a list, and sum the list.

First of all, you should have a container to store those 10 numbers. So you should use a list to store them.

And then `for i in range(list)` just can get the index for each item in the list.

```py
nums = []
for _ in range(0, 10):
  nums.append(int(input()))
return sum(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
total = 0
for _ in range(10):
    total += int(input("Enter a number: "))
print(total)
```

This will ask for a number 10 times, then will print the sum.